# MAC address:pad missing left Zeros

Tags: c++

For example i have a MAC address that has a value of "0:22:3f:a:5d:16", how do i convert this to a human readable format like "00:22:3f:0a:5d:16"?
My mac Address has missing leading zeros because i use

```
string asd = ether_ntoa ((struct ether_addr *)p->add2);//p->add2 is a unsigned char[6]
```

ether_nota removes the leading zeros,i don't know if there are other ways to store a proper MAC addresses as a string.

Comment: I guess you can just print every byte of the mac address individually by picking into ether_addr members.

Comment: yes i can print them, but how do i store it in a string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [implementation](https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.16.0/ether__ntoa__r_8c_source.html) that causes it to print without zero padding is just a `printf` where they use `%x` instead of `%02x`.  The `struct ether_addr` format is [documented in the man page](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/ether_aton.3.html), and therefore its internals are not private.

```
The structure ether_addr is defined in <net/ethernet.h> as:

struct ether_addr {
    uint8_t ether_addr_octet[6];
}
```

So that being said, I'd implement my own version.  `rz` means reentrant and zero padded here.

```
char *ether_ntoa_rz(const struct ether_addr *addr, char *buf)
{
    sprintf(buf, "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x",
            addr->ether_addr_octet[0], addr->ether_addr_octet[1],
            addr->ether_addr_octet[2], addr->ether_addr_octet[3],
            addr->ether_addr_octet[4], addr->ether_addr_octet[5]);
    return buf;
}
```

The non-reentrant version would just have a static buffer and call the reentrant one.

```
char *ether_ntoa_z(const struct ether_addr *addr)
{
    static char buf[18];    /* 12 digits + 5 colons + null terminator */
    return ether_ntoa_rz(addr, buf);
}
```

If you want to look at the implementation of the function in glibc, you can [find it if you search](https://www.google.com/search?q=glibc%20ether_ntoa_r.c).